# Historical Fiction: using you and thou

Tags: word-choice, language, translation, historical-fiction

Generally speaking, English once used 'you' as the second person plural (equivalent to 'vous' and 'vós') and 'thou' as the second person singular (equivalent to 'tu'). When talking to a person in a higher position, one would use the polite 'you' rather than the informal 'thou'. Nevertheless, as time went by, the polite 'you' (nearly) erased 'thou' from existence and became a simple form of treatment without distinction between formal and informal.

I'm attempting to translate a historical novel set in medieval times. The use of the formal/polite 'vous'/'vós' often gives subtle but important cues for the plot, therefore I decided the simplest way of maintaining these cues would be to use 'thou' and 'you'.

Technically speaking, 'thou'='tu' and 'you'='vous'/'vós'. However, usage has caused modern speakers (I believe) to see 'thou' as more formal than 'you'.

Should I then translate 'vous'/'vós' as 'thou' and 'tu' as 'you'? And would that suffice to transmit to the English readers the aforementioned cues?

Comment: You might also ask or search on History SE to see if anyone's addressed or mentioned this issue.

Comment: You first talk about a plural/singular difference and then talk about a difference of formality.  How does what you said about number factor into your question?  Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I know that in Iberian languages the second (and the first) person plural were first used with their normal plural functions. Then they were adopted as royal pronouns. With time, the second person plural was also used as a form of polite treatment. It is essential to denote the difference between 'thou'-'ye' because of levels of informality-formality in the text being translated, but then I will also have to respect the singular-plural difference for coherence sake.

Comment: You might also find helpful information under the [thou-thee-thy](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thou-thee-thy) tag on the English site.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Using the plural *you* for a formal *you* is very common in Romance languages (French, Italian, Spanish, I assume Portuguese), and is also used in English literally as "the Royal You/We."

Comment: @LaurenIpsum (and Sara), makes sense, thanks.

Comment: One Interesting fact. I'm from Russia and we have words "ты, вы", pronounced like "ty, vy", meaning "you" and difference in using also is in formal/informal conversation. I'm interested in history of languages, what is the name and year of the novel?

Comment: It is The Infanta / The Princess. It is set in the mid 14th century Iberian Peninsula.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that Tolkien used almost precisely this, using *thee* to indicate formality in the speech of Gondor, but also using it for familiarity when Éowen says to Aragorn *because they love thee*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I agree with Lew: If you use an archaic form, use it correctly. Singular: thou/þou, plural: ye/ȝe (use either thorn and yogh *or* "th" and "y", don't mix them up!). If you use these archaic forms, explain them in a preface.

But my recommendation is to not use these achaic forms.

"Thou" and "ye" will be a constant irritation to contemporary English readers and an obstacle to immersion. If you use them, you force your readers' attention on an aspect of the book that readers of the French original do not notice at all.

You are translating a novel from French to contemporary English, not from French to Middle English, so you should use contemporary English. There will be many other words and expressions that you cannot translate literally but have to translate by using different construction or a paraphrase. This is one of those cases.

How do other translators handle the difference between singular and plural pronoun, between familiar and polite address? How do native speakers of English address a higher ranking individual in a formal manner? They all manage without reverting to Middle English.

---

There are many possibilities to convey formality versus informality without reverting to archaic pronouns. Instead of opposing "Thou, Madame" to "Ye, Madame", you could use more or less formal versions of the title. One character might say "You, Madame", the other "You, Joan", that is, one uses the name, which will be considered familiar, the other the title, which is more formal and polite. Or you can use "Madame" in opposition to "Mistress" or "Milady" (or whatever other titles where used back then – do some research).

Apparently, the usage is discussed among the characters in the novel, so there is no danger that the readers will miss it. If a character in the French original says something like "Why do you say 'thou'? That is impolite!", let him say "Why do you say 'Joan'? That is impolite!".

Comment: In this particular instance, the plot requires it. A couple's relationship is defined by their formal, succint treatment; the couple's son rebels against this stiffling way of living love and marriage and uses the informal, loving treatment in his personal life, for which he is often criticised. Again, the dialogues are not long and definitely not wordy. There are two instances where the sentence would simply be 'you, madame', but one character says 'thou, madame' while the other says 'ye, madame'. How else to convey this?

Comment: @SaraCosta I see the challenge you are facing, and I my trust is in the readers, adopting to the outdated convention—it is not that hard. I can also see another level of this challenge: if "thou" and "ye" are the _only_ archaisms you employ, and the rest is written in modern language, those two words might not feel natural.

Comment: @SaraCosta That is not difficult at all. See my edit.

Comment: "Ye, Madame" is WRONG - _ye_ is the plural form. It should be _you_ as distinct from _thou_.

Answer (score 12):

> ...usage has caused modern speakers (I believe) to see 'thou' as more formal than 'you'.

I do not think so. It is not *more formal*, if anything, it is archaic, or literary, or both, but you definitely should not switch the actual single/plural meaning of the words, that would be very confusing. I suggest  to use *ye* for the plural of *thou* to equalize the impact.

Comment: I like that idea a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If it was me, I'd distinguish by using "you all" for the plural form, which is *a more modern way to do it*.

However, I happen to live in a dialect area where "you all" is very common, so others might find that odd.

You could pick whichever one of the below second-person plurals most strikes your fancy:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that would be anachronistic for a historical novel set in the 14th century. Interesting map, though. Now I wonder if the Uk has a similar approach to the problem... I may just pose the question over at ELU.

Comment: Some places in the North East and East Midlands retain forms for informal use derived from "thou" etc., but generally it's not common in the UK to have such a distinction. I hear "you all" (not abbreviated to the extent of the Southern American version) and "you guys" (among the younger population exposed to more American influence) a lot, can't think of any others right now but I'm sure someone else can step in.

Comment: @SaraCosta. Here in the middle of Ireland, I'd find *ye* far more natural than *you all*. I myself use *ye* all the time: it's a normal part of my speech. Other parts of Ireland (Dublin and NI) use *youse*.

Comment: @SaraCosta - That's a really confusing response. For a historical novel set in the 14th Century to **not** be anachronistic, the dialog would have to be in [Middle English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English) (and perhaps [Anglo-Norman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Norman_language)) which many modern readers (myself among them) would not be able to understand at all. If you aren't doing that, then the discussion is already about what modern language to translate it into.

Comment: Here's what non-anachronistic 14th Century English would look like (from a 1371 Epitaph): "man com & se how schal alle ded li: wen yolk comes bad & bare
 moth have ben ve awaẏ fare: All ẏs wermēs yt ve for care:—
bot yt ve do for god ẏs luf ve haue nothyng yare:
 yis graue lẏs John ye smẏth god yif his soule hewn grit"

Comment: @T.E.D.: If you talk to Historical Fiction fans, they will tell you the fine distinctions between 'anachronism for readability's sake' and 'anachronism'. I'm afraid that 'you all' and the lot is just too modern to go through that sieve.

Comment: @SaraCosta - Got a link? Genuinely curious about the difference. Only having read about 7 such works myself, I guess I'm not enough of a fan to have encountered that.

Comment: Try visiting Good Reads and checking out the group Ancient and Medieval Historical Fiction. Head to the forums, choose General Discussions and read the thread Historical Accuracy in Fiction. It's rather long, but the general ideas get somewhat repeated as people head there to vent about inaccuracies, whether it's events, objects (like potatoes in Europe before the discovery of the Americas) or the language.

Comment: A couple of quotes:

Comment: A book about ancient Rome includes: ‘OK. Steady, lads, keep low,’ Sabinus growled.
comment: "Agreed, Ok is not okay. In my opinion, neither is 'Ok, steady lads.' The whole thing sounds a bit too...England to me and as i have stated before, i have a big issue with Romans sounding like Englishmen." Just so you can have an idea of what some would call nit-picking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50453/discussion-between-t-e-d-and-sara-costa).